# react native componetWillUpdate not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I am trying to render a component with already existing data from state (provided from redux-persist), the data in is state.login.user (i can see it in console.log in the mapStateToProps function that is being called and returns the dataObject : state.login.user but the dataObject is not being updated and because of that componentWillReceiveProps is not being called.

Can you point me to what im doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { ScrollView, AppRegistry, Component, Text, Image, View, Button, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { GiftedForm, GiftedFormManager } from 'react-native-gifted-form'

// Styles
import styles from './Styles/MyProfileScreenStyles'

class MyProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    const dataObject = {
      profile: {
        last_name : undefined,
      }
    }
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      form: {
        lastName: dataObject.profile.last_name,
        tos: false
      }
    }
  }

  handleValueChange (values) {
    this.setState({form: values})
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
    console.tron.log("componend will receive")
    console.tron.log(newProps)
    if (newProps.dataObject) {
      this.setState({
        dataObject: newProps.dataObject
      })
    }
  }
  render () {
    const {lastName, tos, gender} = this.state.form
    console.log('render', this.state.form)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GiftedForm
          formName='signupForm'
          openModal={(route) => { this.props.navigator.push(route) }}
          onValueChange={this.handleValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <GiftedForm.TextInputWidget
            name='lastName'
            title='Last name'
            placeholder='Last name'
            clearButtonMode='while-editing'
            value={lastName}
          />
          <GiftedForm.HiddenWidget name='tos' value={tos}/>
        </GiftedForm>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  if( state.login.user !== null){
    console.tron.log("test map state to props")
    return {
      dataObject: state.login.user
    }
  }
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyProfileScreen)
```

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is only called when the props are updated after the component has rendered, before the component is re-rendered. You'll want to set the state inside your constructor as the props should already be there.

Comment: How do you set the props to the state.login.user?

Comment: In your constructor you define a `dataObject` when you should just use `props.dataObject`.

Comment: In this.state put `dataObject: props.dataObject`